# Sufficient conditions for a quotient algebra to be finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic

Here's the set up. I have a finite set of elementary letters, and a finite set of operations on the set and I form the free algebra. For concreteness, let's imagine I have two binary operations $\land$ and $\lor$. (But I'm interested in general solutions). I then have a congruence relation $\equiv$ that "forces" the operations to have certain properties. Or rather, forces the quotient algebra to have certain properties. So if $a \land b \equiv b\land a$ for every $a,b$, then $\land$ is commutative in the quotient algebra.

What I'd like to know is this: what conditions restrict the quotient algebra to being finite?

I guess the DNF theorem for logic is an example of this kind of argument, but I'm interested in a more general form...

Comment: In full generality this is almost certainly undecidable. If you restrict to just group axioms + relations, the word problem is undecidable in general.

Comment: Actually it's even slightly worse since the problem of whether a finitely presented group is finite is only recursively enumerable not recursive.

Comment: Ok, well, I guess I'm interested in the cases where there is a solution. For example, If you have "and" "or" and "not" of classical propositional logic as your connectives, then you show that every well formed formula is a unique disjunction of atoms, and there are finitely many atoms. That's the DNF. I'm guessing a similar thing can be done for a distributive lattice (but I'm not sure)...

Comment: I think you're looking for the notion of a [locally finite variety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_finite_variety) of algebras.

Comment: More information here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/87106/when-finitely-generated-free-algebras-are-finite